# How to combine result of SQL statement using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have wrote a query which gives me result in separate rows but issue is that I want that result in single row.

Which gives result like below

Here count is having two possibilities **yes or no**.

but i want something like

for entire result i want to combine for same system name, is there any way to do this.

Comment: You ask for single column but give an output example with three columns :-?

Comment: Updated question @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `where service.ip_port in (select ip_port from service)` an attempt to filter out NULLs? Because I think `WHERE service.ip_port IS NOT NULL` feels way more natural.

Comment: again sorry typo its status.ip_port not service.ip_port

Answer (score 1):

The [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function accepts complex expressions, not just column names. I don't think I fully understand what your data contains or what you want to accomplish but you can try something on this line:

```
SELECT service.sys_name AS sysname,
COUNT(CASE status.status WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 END) AS count_yes,
COUNT(CASE status.status WHEN 'no'  THEN 1 END) AS count_no
...
```

This will omit `NULL` values.

Comment: @Bhagya This is almost the right query. The problem is that you want a filter on the `service.sys_name` field to remove the numbers from it. You have to define the rule for that. One can not assume that the name has always one number and it is only at the end of the string. If you define this rule you probably will get a update on this answer.

Comment: And for the answer, this should be SUM, not COUNT, count will count whether it is 1 or 0.

Comment: I made some quick edits to fine tune the code and inadvertently made it wrong. If should be fine now.

Comment: @JorgeCampos SQLFiddle must be down right now but I understand what you mean—I made the typo while making edits. Of course, when counting `yes` we don't need to care about `no`.

Comment: That should be fine now. I will remove the downvote. Thanks for being polite about it :)